# vb.net need help figuring out this logic in code

Tags: vb.net

i made a app the connects to facebook and pulls off a group of links leading to each post on a group page and i want to check each link ever 30 seconds to see of the link has changed position in the array which would ether mean a new post has been posted or a new post has been pinned or a post has been updated. i have some psudo code of what i think i need to make but i need help figuring out how to do the logic at the bottom were it checks if the data of the array has changed then check if it just moved down one spot in the array

```
set var1 = "void1"
set var2 = "void2"
set var3 = "void3"

set array = ("Data1","Data2","Data3")

check if var1 = array(0)    // "void1" = "Data1" = new_data
check if var2 = array(1)    // "void2" = "Data2" = new_data
check if var3 = array(2)    // "void3" = "Data3" = new_data

set var1 = array(0) // "Data1"
set var2 = array(1) // "data2"
set var3 = array(2) // "data3"

check if var1 = array(0)    // "Data1" = "Data1" = old_data
check if var2 = array(1)    // "Data2" = "Data2" = old_data
check if var3 = array(2)    // "Data3" = "Data3" = old_data

array = ("Data0","Data1","Data2")

set var1 = array(0) // "Data0"
set var2 = array(1) // "data1"
set var3 = array(2) // "data2"

check if var1 = array(0)    // "Data1" = "Data0" = new_data     
check if var2 = array(1)    // "Data2" = "Data1" = new_data     does array(1) = var1    "Data1" = "Data1" change to old_data
check if var3 = array(2)    // "Data3" = "Data2" = new_data     does array(2) = var2    "Data2" = "Data2" change to old_data
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you'll need to do is, per iteration, have an original list of links, then a new one, which you'll compare on an item to item basis (though we need to know whether new links will go to the beginning of the list when you grab them). If the items are not the same, update the 'initial' list with the new list's contents. Some pseudo-code:

```
InitialList = grabLinks() 
Every 30 seconds:
    NewList = grabLinks()
    If Not InitialList(0) = NewList(0) Then 
        InitialList = NewList
    End If
```

You will probably need to use a built-in timing function for polling every thirty seconds.